# Versions of ListItems in SharePoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, versioning

i need to to create/access versions of SharePoint-ListItems (major/minor versions) using REST.
If I understand the [SharePoint 2013 REST Syntax (wall posters)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41147) correct, than it should be possible to access/create versions of SharePoint ListItems using the SharePoint REST API.
But that part of the API is apparently not implemented in the [SharePoint Patterns and Practices Reusable Client-side Libraries](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/), and I could not find an example or anything to that regards ;
so does the SharePoint REST API supports creating/accessing (major/minor) versions of ListItems- and is there an example available ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (only tried a GET request, though):

```
https://server/site/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/site/Lists/someList/1_.000')/Versions
```

Answer (score 0):

It is (now?) possible to easily access all versions of a listitem by using the PnP Library (PNP Powershell).

To give an example:

Say you have a list called 'Cars' and you want access all versions of the listitem with ID 199, then you can use the following code to lead them into an array called $versions

```
$output = Invoke-PnPSPRestMethod -Url "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Cars')/items(199)/Versions/"
$versions = $output.value | Sort-Object {[int]$_.OData__x005f_UIVersion}
```

The sorting on the field OData__x005f_UIVersion is used to make sure that the oldest version is first in the array.

We can then loop through these versions and access their properties just as regular listitems:

```
foreach ($version in $versions){
   write-host $version.Title
   write-host $version.Modified
}
```

As to **creating** versions of listitems with the API, there is no separate functionality for that: when you edit an item (either with the User Interface or with the API), with Versioning Enabled in the list settings, versions are automatically created.